# HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream() takes 20 seconds. Why?

Tags: java, android, web-services

I'm trying to perform webservice calls in android (2.3.4) using the following code snippet. My problem occurs on conn.getOutputStream, as this method seems to be taking a full 20 seconds to return. Any thoughts?

```
URL uri = new URL(serviceURI + "/remoteMethod");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Log.d(TAG, "opening output stream");
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
    conn.getOutputStream());
Log.d(TAG, "output stream opened");

String body = getRequestBody();
writer.write(body);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
int responseCode= conn.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: Although this does not directly answer your question, I would recommend performing the fetch using Androids AsyncTask, this way you can update your UI notifying your user of the wait. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: This is all happening outside my UI thread in a subclass of IntentService, and the question has little if anything to do with usability patterns at that.

Comment: And it is not because of the obvious reason that it actually may take 20 seconds to connect to the server?

Comment: It's a possibility, but I somewhat doubt it, since the server is a dev environment on the local network, and otherwise the server appears to be functioning normally.

Comment: Well getOutputStream() really only does a connect() and maybe DNS lookups, has to be one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this was probably a network problem, and that jarnbjo was actually correct in his suggestion in the comments that the connection was just taking too long. I moved the server and device to another network (webservice is not public), and the problem cleared up.