# Jersey taking a long time to return result

Tags: java, jersey

Been trying to figure out what's going on here all day, and a bit stumped. Repeated calls to the same web API consistently return in <1000ms as expected. The `API` is hosted on the `LAN` on a different machine. However, sometimes, the calls take up to 7 seconds. It's not a GC issue, because `GC` isn't happening when I see these anomalies.

When looking into this using `VisualVM`, the following comes up.

All I can think is that there is perhaps some network issue returning the payload to my machine (the caller). Anyone seen this before?

[image: Visual VM Output]

Comment: Did you check for concurrent requests on the same resource?

Comment: Yes I did, it's a DEV server, very quiet except for me hitting it from postman

Comment: Did you get the latency issues after code updates?

Comment: Sortof, some users were complaining about API speed. We performed some optimizations on the business logic which reduced the time of calls from 5 seconds on average to 600ms. We see this consistently except for the odd one that has this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream() takes 20 seconds. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744453/httpurlconnection-getoutputstream-takes-20-seconds-why)

Comment: Possibly, except we aren't making connections using Jersey. We're using Jersey-spring to manage jaxws. But yes, I'm also thinking this is network related :(

Comment: Have you tried talking to it from the local machine?

Comment: I wrote a script last night to hit the web service every 30 seconds. This issue persists, so it's not the network...